# Does fitting a model to a new data set overwrite previous training progress?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'd like to implement some active learning algorithm ([modAL](https://modal-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/examples/Keras_integration.html)) with Keras. But I'd like to know whether initiating multiple training instances (i.e., running .fit() more than once) will build on previous training, or if the weights are reset. In other words, is training additive or iterative?

In case training starts from scratch each time, is there a way to have the model build on previous training?

Comment: Please post your code here (as text), not in an external link.

Answer (score 1):

For a given iteration the inputs are provided to the network with the network weights set to a certain value. For each applied input back propagation is used to calculate a gradients. For a batch size of 100 ,100 inputs are applied and the resultant 100 gradients averaged to  determine a new value for the network weights. These weights are then used to process the next batch of 100 inputs. So the process is iterative not additive. There are many possible explanations for why the network appears not to be learning.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you have an answer for how to build on previous training?